# what is MQTT url to my thingsboard instance

Tags: mqtt, thingsboard

I have a thingsboard UI available at "thingsboard.MYDOMAIN.io:8080".  I'm using NodeJS and MQTT.js.  I can connect using the sample code on that page.  But I don't know what URL i would use in that connect string. I've tried using that URL and putting MQTT:// on the front of it to no avail.

It's just one device coming into a thingsboard. I wouldn't think i would need to add anything other than the default thingsboard.

If someone could tell what the expect default URL would be?

Answer (score 0):

The default MQTT  port number is 1883 so something like

```
mqtt://thingsboard.mydomain.io:1883
```

would be a good starting point. You should even be able to leave the port number off e.g.

```
mqtt://thingsboard.mydomain.io
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection code should be something like this:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

const thingsboardHost = "127.0.0.1";
const ACCESS_TOKEN = "**********";

// Initialization of mqtt client using Thingsboard host and device access token
console.log('Connecting to: %s using access token: %s', thingsboardHost, ACCESS_TOKEN);
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://'+ thingsboardHost, { username: ACCESS_TOKEN });
```

The default MQTT port number is 1883, but you don't have to manually set that value. Take a look at the source code.

https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js